# nvd3 segment color change

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

My data points for the line graph is like the following:

```
Point [{ data : 5, status : 1 ,color : red },{ data : 5, status : 2 ,color : yellow }
```

How to draw different segment color lines graph Using NVD3 ?

Comment: First you must try something...

Comment: I tried in high chart(paid) and google char (offline wont work) , without knowing i tried one by one,but in NVD3 i am not getting any such option

Comment: Why have you added tag `D`?

Comment: @sigod must be a typo, I removed it

Comment: @TimB at least once a week someone makes such typo. I wonder how it happens.

Comment: @sigod they start to type `d3`, the autocompletion show the tag, and then they press `space` I guess